# Include a c# file in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page that has a @Page directive which points to a c# class. e.g.

```
<@ Page Language="C#" EnableSessionState="true" ValidateRequest="False" Inherits="MyClass" %>
```

MyClass extends Page, which is the code behind class for that aspx page.

Now I want to add another class to the aspx page.  This class does some processing and will redirect the user to another page if certain conditions are met.  It will be called before the above directive.  I tried adding another @Page directive, but gotten an unknown error (literally).  I'm thinking that there can only be one code behind class per aspx page so I got the error when I added another one.  Googling such question didnt really help me with the answer.

So, how do I add another c# class to the same aspx page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another class which extends Page class and then add the newly created class as the  parent of your web page.

```
public class MyBaseClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
       // ... add custom logic here ...

       // Be sure to call the base class's OnLoad method!
       base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}

public class WebForm1 : MyBaseClass
{
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Put user code to initialize the page here
    }

    ...
}
```

See this

**[Using a Custom Base Class for your ASP.NET Pages' Code-Behind Classes](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx)**

Comment: @rahul: I followed your example.  In my aspx page, I have the inherit set to WebForm1.  What happened was that the order of methods called was not what I was expecting: 1) WebForm1.OnInit, 2) MyBaseClass.OnInit, 3) WebForm1.Page_Load, 4) MyBaseClass.Page_Load.  Is this the right behaviour?  I would prefer the logic in MyBaseClass to get run first. Thanks.